# Pandas resample behaves differently with SUM and MEAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

```
python==3.8.10
pandas==2.0.3 (cannot update to python >= 3.9, so I am stuck to this version)
```

A dataframe contains some hourly data for a year. I filter the data to remove the months from April to October, and then aggregate by DAY. That should mean 151 days are left.

**Is there any reason why MEAN and SUM are calculated on a different number of rows?**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet(BASE_DIR + "hour_fw_temp2022.parquet")  # load hour data
df = df[(df.index.month < 4)|(df.index.month > 10)]   # remove April to October
df = df.resample("1D").mean()   # aggregate per day

df.describe()
```

returns

```
             temp         rh%             fw
count  151.000000  151.000000     151.000000  <=== MEAN calculated on 151 days
mean     3.725442   77.780077   96365.618102
std      4.281750   12.593718   21074.110945
min     -9.304167   25.500000   44666.666667
25%      1.254167   72.125000   82250.000000
50%      3.420833   80.125000  100083.333333
75%      6.814583   85.937500  109395.833333
max     14.091667   98.041667  166333.333333
```

while

```py
df = df.resample("1D").sum()   # aggregate per day
```

returns

```
             temp          rh%            fw
count  365.000000   365.000000  3.650000e+02  <== SUM calculated on 365 days
mean    36.989041   772.260274  9.567918e+05
std     79.347405   940.838631  1.185907e+06
min   -223.300000     0.000000  0.000000e+00  <== removed rows are filled with 0
25%      0.000000     0.000000  0.000000e+00      and all the stats are wrong...
50%      0.000000     0.000000  0.000000e+00
75%     53.600000  1849.000000  2.224000e+06
max    338.200000  2353.000000  3.992000e+06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By resampling, you equalize the frequency of the periodic index to a specified value. Any aggregation performed afterwards is based on the same data structure and returns the same number of records. The difference is in the behavior of an aggregation function. To force `sum` to return `Nan` instead of zeros for empty data, you may need to include an additional parameter `min_count=1`, which is 0 by default:

```
df = df.resample("1D").sum(min_count=1)
```

See [documentation for detailes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum.html)

Comment: @@Vitalizzare, Thank you, I never heard of this parameter. As I understand it, I believe it is quite non intuitive and mathematically dangerous: if an interval has no values it should return NaN as sum by default, instead of 0. Why MEAN doesn't do the same as SUM is above my understanding.

Also, the need to use a lambda in `df = df.resample("1D").agg({"temp":"mean", "rh%":"mean", "fw":"sum"})` and change "sum" to `lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1)`. Ugly.

Answer (score 1):

**Mimal and Rrproducible Example**

This kind of problem can be solved immediately by creating a reproducible example. That's why SO asks for [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when answering questions.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-01', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'])
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=idx, columns=['col1'])
```

df

```
            col1
2022-01-01  1
2022-01-03  2
2022-01-04  3
```

---

**Code**

1. `resample` + `sum`

```
out1 = df.resample('D')['col1'].sum()
```

out1

```
2022-01-01    1
2022-01-02    0
2022-01-03    2
2022-01-04    3
```

2. `resample` + `mean`

```
out2 = df.resample('D')['col1'].mean()
```

out2

```
2022-01-01    1.0
2022-01-02    NaN
2022-01-03    2.0
2022-01-04    3.0
```

`mean` return NaN (count = Non-null count)

Comment: @AlexPoca Please check answer again. The example `df` does not have data for **2022-01-02**, but it is created after resampling. `mean` is created as NaN and `sum` is created as 0. NaN is excluded from the application of all statistical functions, while 0 is included.

Comment: but WHY does it happen? Filling with 0 the missing rows (that has been filtered out) change the statistics! I cannot understand why mathematically it is accepted to add missing values as 0..

Comment: @AlexPoca This is a characteristic of resample. (This characteristic can actually be helpful in many cases.) If you don't want it, apply a conditional statement to the resample result. or use `min_count=1` like Vitalizzare answer